# sql window functions based on start flag and end flag of a row

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata, window-functions

I have data in a table currently have data like below.
I want number rows based on `child_start` and `child end` columns using window functions.

Data Sample

```
LoadNumber |DispatchNumber|ChildLoadStart|ChildLoadEnd  |
---------------------------------------------------------
123        | A            |1             |1             |
---------------------------------------------------------
123        |B             |1             |0             |
---------------------------------------------------------
123        |C             |0             |0             |
---------------------------------------------------------
123        |D             |0             |1             |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above data for a load 123 I have two child loads i.e., dispatch A is one child load and dispatch B,C,D form one more child load.
So I need to number the each child loads like below;
the result should be something like below. Can some one help me on this?

```
LoadNumber |DispatchNumber|ChildLoadStart|ChildLoadEnd  |Order         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
123        | A            |1             |1             |1             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123        |B             |1             |0             |1             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123        |C             |0             |0             |2             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123        |D             |0             |1             |3             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: please make an effort to post the sample data and the expected result as text instead of images.

Comment: And explain the logic to assign those numbers

Comment: If B,C,D are the same "child load" then why don't they have the same identifier? (e.g. dispatchnumber)

Answer (score 1):

If `DispatchNumber` can be used to order the data:

```
ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY LoadNumber
      ORDER BY DispatchNumber
      RESET WHEN ChildLoadStart = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `reset when` clause proposed by @dnoeth is exactly what is needed here. But I'm not familiar with Teradata so below is the Oracle alternative, maybe this will be useful for someone.

At first divide your data into groups using cumulative sum and then use this column (`grp`) in `partition by clause` for `row_number()`:

```
select loadnumber, dispatchnumber, childloadstart, childloadend, 
       row_number() over (partition by loadnumber, grp order by dispatchnumber) as "ORDER"
  from (
    select data.*,
           sum(childloadstart) over (partition by loadnumber order by dispatchnumber) grp
      from data )
```

Test data and output:

```
create table data (LoadNumber number(4), DispatchNumber varchar2(2), 
                   ChildLoadStart number(1), ChildLoadEnd number(1));

insert into data values (123, 'A', 1, 1);
insert into data values (123, 'B', 1, 0);
insert into data values (123, 'C', 0, 0);
insert into data values (123, 'D', 0, 1);

LOADNUMBER DISPATCHNUMBER CHILDLOADSTART CHILDLOADEND      ORDER
---------- -------------- -------------- ------------ ----------
       123 A                           1            1          1
       123 B                           1            0          1
       123 C                           0            0          2
       123 D                           0            1          3
```